# Reading bitmap resource into Uri

Tags: c#, bitmap, datagrid, resources

I am writing a code that is using file path to read images from a folder (`.gif`) and stores them in `datagridObject` so I can show them later in `dataGrid`.

The code looks like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Images_File);
var L = new List<DataGridObject>();
for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
        {
            var d = new DataGridObject();

            d.MainName = list_MainName[z];
            d.Level = list_Level[z];
            d.Exp = list_Exp[z];

            d.ImageSource = new Uri(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.gif", Images_File, list_MainName[z]), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            L.Add(d);

        }

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

However, I would like to make it an `.exe` file which will have all the image file as resources.

I embedded the images as a resource and I tried using:

```
 d.ImageSource = new Bitmap(namespace.Properties.Resources.list_MainName[z]);
```

but im getting an error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type System.Drawing,Bitmap to System.Uri`.

Is there a good way to use image resources inside a for loop and store them into an object?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Resources file and then add images to this file as required.
We can iterate over the images using [`ResourceReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx).

```cs
public Dictionary<string,Bitmap> GetEmbeddedImages()
{
    // Add a new Resources file named Resource1.resx; VS will generate a static class named Resource1
    // Add images to this file as required

    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceName = String.Format("{0}.{1}.resources", assembly.GetName().Name, typeof(Resource1).Name);

    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> images = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();

    using (var rStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (var rReader = new ResourceReader(rStream))
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in rReader)
        {
            var itemName = (string)de.Key;
            var itemValue = (Bitmap)de.Value;

            images.Add(itemName, itemValue);
        }
    }

    return images;
}
```